# Elasticsearch: Wrong facet terms result

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, facet

I want to implement facet filters on my products list page using elasticsearch.
Basically my product document index contains a number of products which contains a number of variations.

The variations are defines as "nested" objects in order to make sure only products are returned where a variation matches all filter criteria.
The filtering the variations seems to work correct. However the facets results are not as I would expect a facet filter to work.

For example my query below returns the terms "oriental" and "citrus" for the facet "f_attribute_scent". However I only want to get back the term that matched my filter which would be "citrus".

I have tried out a lot of different things with facet filters and everything but I just can't get it to work correctly.

My mapping looks like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/products -d '
{
   "mappings": {
      "de": {
         "properties": {
            "variants": {
               "type": "nested",
               "include_in_parent": true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Here is my test data:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/products/de/12 -d '
{
    "id": "12",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "12345",
            "sort": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "23456",
            "sort": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "34567",
            "sort": "3"
        }
    ],
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "12.1.1",
            "brand": "guerlain",
            "collection": "emporio",
            "rating": 4,
            "color": "green",
            "price": 31,
            "scent": "fruity"
        },
        {
            "id": "12.1.2",
            "brand": "guerlain",
            "collection": "emporio",
            "rating": 2,
            "color": "blue",
            "price": 49.99,
            "scent": "flowery"

        }
    ]
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/products/de/15 -d '
{
    "id": "15",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "12345",
            "sort": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "23456",
            "sort": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "34567",
            "sort": "3"
        }
    ],
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "15.1.1",
            "brand": "dior",
            "collection": "foobar",
            "rating": 4,
            "color": "green",
            "price": 48.00,
            "scent": "oriental"
        },
        {
            "id": "15.1.2",
            "brand": "dior",
            "collection": "foobar",
            "rating": 2,
            "color": "red",
            "price": 52,
            "scent": "citrus"
        }
    ]
}'
```

This is the query:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/products/de/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "variants",
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "terms": {
                              "variants.color": [
                                 "green",
                                 "red"
                              ]
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "variants.scent": "citrus"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "f_attribute_color": {
         "terms": {
            "all_terms": true,
            "field": "variants.color"
         }
      },
      "f_attribute_scent": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "variants.scent"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

... And the result:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "products",
            "_type": "de",
            "_id": "15",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": "15",
               "categories": [
                  {
                     "id": "12345",
                     "sort": "1"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "23456",
                     "sort": "2"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "34567",
                     "sort": "3"
                  }
               ],
               "variants": [
                  {
                     "id": "15.1.1",
                     "brand": "dior",
                     "collection": "foobar",
                     "rating": 4,
                     "color": "green",
                     "price": 48,
                     "scent": "oriental"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "15.1.2",
                     "brand": "dior",
                     "collection": "foobar",
                     "rating": 2,
                     "color": "red",
                     "price": 52,
                     "scent": "citrus"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "facets": {
      "f_attribute_color": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 2,
         "other": 0,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "red",
               "count": 1
            },
            {
               "term": "green",
               "count": 1
            }
         ]
      },
      "f_attribute_scent": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 2,
         "other": 0,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "oriental",
               "count": 1
            },
            {
               "term": "citrus",
               "count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data examples above that is being indexed, you are seeing both `citrus` and `oriental` as terms facets results because your documents have `variants` as an array and both of those terms are valid for the document that matched your query.

From the [Elasticsearch Facets Documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html):

> There’s one important distinction to keep in mind. While search queries restrict both the returned documents and facet counts, search filters restrict only returned documents — but not facet counts.
>
> If you need to restrict both the documents and facets, and you’re not willing or able to use a query, you may use a facet filter.

Based on the documentation and the desired results that you are asking for, you may want to look into using a [Filter Facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-filter-facet.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested docs are being indexed in two ways:

1. as independent documents, one for each element in the `variants` array, and
2. in the top level `de` document as if you had set the `variants` field to be type `object`

The reason for (2) above is that you set `include_in_parent` to `true`. So actually, the top level doc looks like:

```
{
    "id": "12",
    "variants.id":    [ "12.1.1","12.1.2"],
    "variants.brand": [ "guerlain", "guerlain"],
    "variants.color": [ "green", "blue"]
    ... etc ...
}
```

Your query uses the `nested` filter correctly, which identifies the top level documents which match, but then you facet on the top-level doc, not the nested docs, which is why you are getting all of the results.

To fix it, all you need to do is to change your facets to use the nested docs instead, and to
add the same nested filter that you used in your main query as a `facet_filter`:

```
"facets": {
  "f_attribute_color": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "variants.color"
     },
     "nested": "variants",
     "facet_filter": {
        "bool": {
           "must": [
              {
                 "terms": {
                    "variants.color": [
                       "green",
                       "red"
                    ]
                 }
              },
              {
                 "term": {
                    "variants.scent": "citrus"
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  },
  "f_attribute_scent": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "variants.scent"
     },
     "nested": "variants",
     "facet_filter": {
        "bool": {
           "must": [
              {
                 "terms": {
                    "variants.color": [
                       "green",
                       "red"
                    ]
                 }
              },
              {
                 "term": {
                    "variants.scent": "citrus"
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
I added the facets exactly like in your example, but it does not change anything.
I still get "oriental" and "citrus"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you need to filter the nested docs as well.  Answer updated

Comment: Your answer brought me one step ahead just to show a new problem :-). See my answer below

Comment: Rather update your question than adding more question as an answer - this isn't nested or ordered.  And in answer: yes, you are faceting on variations so those are the counts you get.  If you want to facet on the top level, then you can forget about nested facets and use the `regex`parameter to choose which terms you want to include in the terms facets: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html#_regex_patterns

Comment: So in other words it is not possible with elasticsearch to get either the correct facet count or facet terms when using nested objects?
But there must be a solution to this problem. I am sure that I am not the only person trying to accomplish this?

Comment: You *are* getting the correct results for the question you are asking. But you're expecting Elasticsearch to distinguish `brand` from `color` when both are at the same level.  Is the `brand` always the same for every variant? Then move it to the top level.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: If I use your filter facets I only get returned "citrus" for the "scent" facet.

However, if I want to filter by brand name "dior" I have got the same problem again. The facet result returns "dior" with a count of "2". The reason beeing that now both variations have the same brand name:

```
GET /products/de/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "variants",
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "variants.brand": "dior"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "f_attribute_brand": {
         "nested": "variants",
         "facet_filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "variants.brand": "dior"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "terms": {
            "field": "variants.brand"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the result:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "products",
            "_type": "de",
            "_id": "15",
            "_score": 1
         }
      ]
   },
   "facets": {
      "f_attribute_brand": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 2,
         "other": 0,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "dior",
               "count": 2
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```